# How do I find out why I couldn't #destroy() a record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
person = Person.find(4123)
person.destroy #=> false
```

What ways do I have to find out why the record wasn't deleted? The model has two validations, both trigger on create only. It has one callback, but the callback doesn't block if it fails.

I have no traceback or errors to look at.

Comment: Which Rails are you on? Please post your Person model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the exact same error right now. I didn't get any backtrace, because it was a logic error.

In my case my models had a conflicting `dependent: destroy` in the relations in the model. That means my model wanted to delete a parent model which was already deleted before hand.

I think it's a bit confusing, i'll make it clear by declaring the models:

```
class Section < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :contents, dependent: :destroy

class Content < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :section
  has_many :quizzes, dependent: :destroy

class Quiz < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :content, dependent: :destroy
```

I deleted the Section `section.destroy` and got the error. The error was the `dependent: destroy` in the relation :content in the `Quiz`-model, because the content was already deleted by the `dependent: destroy` in the section model. I hope this will help to find the problem :)

Answer (score 48):

**Update**: See Mike Slate's answer for a quicker solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53872915/171183.

I ran into this same issue and here's what I've done to figure out what's going on...

(TL;DR: Complete code listing given at bottom.)

First, for the class of the object I'm trying to destroy, I ran this to figure out what all associations are set as `dependent: :destroy`:

```rb
ary = 
  <MyClass>.reflect_on_all_associations.select { |a| 
    a.options[:dependent] == :destroy 
  }.map(&:name)
```

Then I called each of the associations named in `ary` on my object and collected the results. This limits the association names to only those that actually have dependent objects:

```rb
ary.select! { |association_name| 
  <my_object>.send(association_name).present? 
}
```

Then I can attempt to destroy each of the objects returned by these association names to find the problem object(s):

```rb
associated_objects = 
  ary.each_with_object([]) { |association_name, acc| 
    acc.concat(<my_object>.send(association_name))
  }

problem_objects =
  associated_objects.select { |obj| obj.destroy; obj.errors.any? }
# ...
```

I then could look at the errors on each problem object:

```rb
problem_objects.map(&:errors)
```

And that's where I finally saw the error that was causing the destroy to fail. From there it was a Simple Matter Of Programming (SMOP) to fix the issue.

In my case, there was a `before_destroy` callback preventing destroy from working on one of my dependent object associations. To make this simpler to debug in the future, I've decided to start logging an error to the Rails log on failed callbacks (in addition to adding the error message to `errors.base`).

### Complete code listing:

```rb
my_object = <your_object_here>

ary = 
  my_object.class.reflect_on_all_associations.select { |a| 
    a.options[:dependent] == :destroy 
  }.map(&:name)

ary.select! { |association_name| my_object.send(association_name).present? }

associated_objects = 
  ary.flat_map { |association_name| my_object.send(association_name) }

problem_objects =
  associated_objects.select { |obj| obj.destroy; obj.errors.any? }

problem_objects.map(&:errors)
```

Comment: Thanks, helped me a lot!! In my case I simply had `return false` in the `before_destroy` method which prevented destroying the object.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the 2nd code block. As it is right now, it would select either all or none of the associations in `ary` depending on if the object had any of the first association. Should it be `ary.select! { |a| obj.send(a).any? }` instead?

Answer (score 36):

I've run into this a few times now, and have finally come across a simple means of identifying the reason the record was not destroyed (tested in Rails 5.x).

Simply wrap the call to **destroy!** in a rescue block, and look at error.record.errors.

```
begin
  person = Person.find(4123)
  person.destroy! #=> Note the exclamation mark which will cause an error if it fails
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed => error
  puts "errors that prevented destruction: #{error.record.errors.full_messages}"
end
```

Comment: I'm surprised that this works when `person.destroy; person.errors` doesn't. Good find!

Comment: This worked great except that I needed to use `#{error.record.errors.full_messages}` to display the specific root cause.

Answer (score 5):

This error is usually raised due to a `dependent: :restrict_with_error` specified on an association in the model. Run a quick search for this in your model definition (as well as associated model definitions) and see if that's the case.

Answer (score 2):

What version Rails are you on? In Rails 4, you can force a destroy using `person.destroy!`. If the action fails, a traceback will be displayed.

Comment: That's correct, this will rails a ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed exception

Comment: That's fine, but can you please expand your question to include your `Person` model?

Answer (score 0):

You should add some debug information e.g. logger.debug and look at your log files. e.g. log/production.log if running in production mode and etc and you should be able to find out why. If not, you can post the relevant log file section (e.g. the action you are running) up here and we can help you out.

Comment: Where would you even put log statements to catch this?