# ROR: How to handle with "Failed to destroy the record" execption?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

When i destory a statement with answers it rises an error(and show it in flash).

But when i try to delete test with this statement it rise execption "Failed to destroy the record".

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :statements, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :answers, through: :statements

class Statement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test
  has_many :answers, dependent: :restrict_with_error
```

I need:

- Test to be destroyed when it has Statements and Statetments don't
  have Answers.
- Test not to be destroyed when it has Statement and any of that Statements have Answers.

Smth like this:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :statements, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :answers, through: :statements, dependent: :restrict_with_error
```

My approach:

**test_controller.rb**

```
def destroy
    if @test.destroy
      redirect_to tests_path, notice: 'Good'
    else
      redirect_to tests_path, error: 'Bad'
    end
end
```

My approach raise error:

```
>> @test.destroy
!! #<ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed: Failed to destroy the record>
```

Comment: Whenever a "Test" record is destroyed, do you only want the associated statements to be destroyed automatically? but not destroying the statements' answers?

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario edited my question

Answer (score 1):

Now that your question is a lot clearer:

Your code should be already working properly, as I just tested it with the same models. But, my guess only is that you are not getting the flash message, when destroying a test that has statements that has answers? Then, perhaps you are not setting the flash message errors properly see below.

```
# models/test.rb
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :statements, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :answers, through: :statements

# models/statement.rb
class Statement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test
  has_many :answers, dependent: :restrict_with_error

# controllers/tests_controller.rb
def destroy
  @test = Test.find(params[:id])

  puts @test.errors.full_messages
  # => nil

  if @test.destroy
    puts @test.errors.full_messages
    #=> nil

    redirect_to tests_path, notice: 'Test was successfully destroyed.'

  else
    puts @test.errors.full_messages
    #=> nil

    @test.statements.each do |statement|
      puts statement.errors.full_messages
      # => ["Cannot delete record because dependent answers exist"]

      statement.errors.full_messages do |full_message|
        @test.errors.add(:base, "statement(id: #{statement.id}): #{full_message}")
      end
    end

    puts @test.errors.full_messages
    # => ["statement(id: 1): Cannot delete record because dependent answers exist"]


    redirect_to tests_path, alert: @test.errors.full_messages
  end
end
```

### Tests

Check if my tests reflect my understanding of your question correctly:

**Should NOT destroy Test when it has Statement that has Answer:**

```
irb(main):001:0 > test = Test.create!
irb(main):002:0 > statement = Statement.create!(test: test)
irb(main):003:0 > answer = Answer.create!(statement: statement)
irb(main):004:0 > test_that_has_statement_that_has_answer = test
irb(main):005:0 > test_that_has_statement_that_has_answer.destroy
=> false
irb(main):006:0 > puts test.persisted?
=> true
irb(main):007:0 > puts test_that_has_statement_that_has_answer.errors.full_messages
=> nil
irb(main):008:0 > puts test_that_has_statement_that_has_answer.statements.first.errors.full_messages
=> ["Cannot delete record because dependent answers exist"]
```

**Should destroy Test when it has Statement that has no Answer:**

```
irb(main):001:0 > test = Test.create!
irb(main):002:0 > statement = Statement.create!(test: test)
irb(main):003:0 > test_that_has_statement_that_has_no_answer = test
irb(main):004:0 > test_that_has_statement_that_has_no_answer.destroy
=> #<Test id: 1...>
irb(main):005:0 > puts test.persisted?
=> false
irb(main):006:0 > puts test_that_has_statement_that_has_no_answer.errors.full_messages
=> nil
irb(main):007:0 > puts test_that_has_statement_that_has_no_answer.statements.count
=> 0
# count becomes 0 which means the statement is automatically destroyed as well
```

Comment: In this case Test can not be deleted when it has ANY statement. I edited my question to explain the idea.

Comment: Thx, for the detailed explanation, but now the problem is in the test.destroy method.
`>> @test.destroy`
`!! #<ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed: Failed to destroy the record>`. Added it in my question above.

Comment: @nuT707 seems like your problem is caused by a different reason, because on my end I didn't encounter any `ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed` error. Maybe you have a `before_destroy` callback that causes this error? Or maybe check each associated Statement record that causes the error? Try opening this [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16767415/how-do-i-find-out-why-i-couldnt-destroy-a-record) and see if it helps